# Using this jQuery plugin (not mine) good coding practice?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I hope the question is not too unspecific. At the moment, I am trying to write a plugin for jQuery, but I struggle with the various ways to structure it. I found [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/), and thought this was pretty accessible for plugin code. Here is a simple example:

```
(function($){

$.fn.letSlider = function(options){     

    var defaults = {
        speed: 500,                         
        onBeforeSlide: function(){} //Callback          
    }

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    //cache base element
    base = this;

        //public functions
        this.init = function(){
            text = giveText();
            alert(text + ' ' + options.speed);

        };

        //private functions
        function giveText(){
                return 'blubb';
        };

    this.each(function(){
        // make sure the element has children
        if($(this).children().length > 0){
            base.init();
        }
    });

    return this;                        
}
 })(jQuery);
```

So it has a clear structur which I manage to understand. However, it looks quite different from all plugin structures I have seen advised so far, so I am not sure, if it won't cause me trouble later on. Still, it does basically everything I need: exposed options, callbacks, private and public functions. And with this.each it should be chainable too. One thing I noticed already is that basically everything is in the initial $.fn.bxSlider = function(options){ ... and I have never seen that before.

As far as the other plugin structures go, they are either too complicated for me to grasp (shame on me), or I fail at implementing them. For example, with http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern I failed to make the opts (options variable) available in private or public functions. But I digress. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to use whatever techniques that best suites the plugin your trying to make. The example you gave looks like a good template to start with.

If you were having trouble accessing `opts` is because it's a private variable inside the $.fn.hilight function. So naturally methods defined outside of the same scope can't access it.

In the example you have here, `options` is also a private variable, but the methods defined underneath are in the same scope so they are granted access.

**Example 1:**

```
foo = function () {
  var secret = "foo";
}

foo.bar = function() {
  alert(secret); // NOT OK!
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
foo = function() {
  var secret = "foo";

  this.bar = function() {
    alert(secret); // OK!
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, I was too confused to see the scope yesterday. Actually, the structure I have in the first example does exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if you're following best practices, I would start with [jQuery's own documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) on authoring plugins. They have provided pretty easy-to-follow examples.

Comment: Thanks, though I read that and I thought it was a little too complicated. Basically, I wanted an educated guess on the capabilities of the above structure vs. the jQuery recommendation.